# .htaccess rewrite url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use the rewrite feature of .htaccess in order to rewrite the following url

http://just-for-testing.com/index.php?type=hello

to

http://just-for-testing.com/hello

So I have the following index.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="?type=hello">hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And also the .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However, it is still not working, the url is still link to

```
index.php?type=hello
```

could anyone give a help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how url rewriting works.

Your rule allows you to open both pages pages:

```
http://just-for-testing.com/index.php?type=hello
http://just-for-testing.com/hello
```

Where the second one will be rewritten to the first one so that your `index.php` page gets processed by the server (with the query variable available) and the result gets sent to the browser.

To be able to use that, you should not use your original link in any place, but only use the new urls:

```
<a href="/hello">hello</a>
```